# CSV Powershell If statement filter

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to implement an if statement in my powershell code. I am having trouble adding the other filters, because I do not know how to do that. Below is what I am trying to add.

How can I add the following to the #Excluded Formula? If the row Type0 has anything in the row equal to "Local" and the row Account0 is equal to "ACCOUNTS - DOD","Account-dom","accounts" and if the row UAN is equal to "APA", "DOD","Planstack" then the Excluded Row is to display "True" if not, Ecluded should equal False.

```
 Foreach ($row in $csv) {
 If ($row.Type0 -eq 'Local' -and $row.Account0 -eq 'ACCOUNTS - DODSCAN','')  { 
    $row."Excluded" = "True" 
    Write-Host $row."Excluded"
    } Else { 
    $row."Excluded" = "False" 
  }
 }
```

Below is an image of my csv columns and shows that I am trying to make the excluded column equal true or false going off of the if else statement.
[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zm0zq.png)

Comment: This question is really unclear. What does your data look like? Post an example of data that should lead to `True`, and data that should lead to `False`. Ideally provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @gms0ulman Does it look better and make sense?

Comment: I'm still unclear but have posted an answer based on my understanding of the question and requirements. Please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Still not entirely clear on the full details. But it's clear you are interested in creating a complex `if` statement with multiple criteria.

Assuming that want you want for Excluded to equal `True` is:

- Type0 equals Local exactly (not " Local" or "Local " or "somethingelseLocal"
- Account0 is equal to one of the following: "ACCOUNTS - DOD","Account-dom" or "accounts"
- Unique Account Name is one of the following: "APA", "DOD","Planstack"

Then you can use the following. I have strung the 3 requirements together using `-and`, with brackets around each criteria so you can see what's going on. The `-in` operator is used to check that a value is one of a set; the set is created as an array, e.g. `@(1,2,3)`

```
Foreach ($row in $csv) {

    If (($row.Type0 -eq 'Local') -and ($row.Account0 -in @('ACCOUNTS - DODSCAN','Account-dom','accounts')) -and ($row."Unique Account Name" -in @('APA'.'DOD','Planstack')))  { 
        $row."Excluded" = "True" 
        Write-Host $row."Excluded"
    } Else { 
        $row."Excluded" = "False" 
    }

}
```